# PHP exec() does return nothing

Tags: php, cmd, exec

I want to call a py file with the `exec()` command from PHP.

```
exec("$python_exe $python_script", $output);
echo $output;
```

The py file simply returns a string 'Hello'. 
When I run the php script from the exec function it returns nothing. I tried running the command from cmd and it works. After following some discussions I analyzed the result of command 'whoami'. On cmd, it returns `<computer-name>\<user-name>` instead of php returns `nt authority system`. I tried to change the service properties of Apache from "Local System" to another `user / account` from service.msc. But does not work.I checked also into php.ini `disable_functions`, but the problem in not here.

Any suggestion?
thx.

Comment: Are you sure you are checking the correct php.ini file? I would recommend doing phpinfo() in a page, get the path to the php.ini file and double check the disable_functions in that file.

Comment: I think it's correct. I use wamp and I ran this route after click wamp icon: PHP>php.ini

Comment: yes the path was right -> C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.39\bin\php.ini and disable_functions have no value.

Comment: What is `$python_exe` and  `$python_script`?

Comment: Absolute path. $python_exe - path to python.exe. $python_script - path to python script

Comment: nobody can help me?

Answer (score 0):

`$output` will be of an array type. You can check its value by `print_r($output)` as below:

```
$output = '';
exec("$python_exe $python_script", $output);
print_r($output);
```

Hope it helps you!!

Comment: this work:
`exec("echo 'hello';", $output);
print_r($output);`
but not this: 
`exec("$python_exe $python_script", $output); 
print_r($output);`

Comment: Can you show values inside these variables? $python_exe $python_script ??

Comment: Absolute path. $python_exe - path to python.exe. $python_script - path to python script